how can i find message window in Quartus
There are no messages window below the code blocks
I'm using Quartus eda tool for fpga jobs with verilog HDL.
For compiling, i need message window to know errors in my code blocks.
But i can't find message window
that indicate errors below the code blocks.
I wanted to extend code blocks so i dragged with my mouse and reduced messages window.
I compiled my code blocks but no messages window appeared.
So, I tried to solve problems in two ways but it didn't worked.
First, I tried rebooting the program.
Next, i clicked the window bar but message window didn't appear.
Thanks for reading. Hopes for good answers.

Alt+3 or View>Utility Windows>Messages
